# C# Is Type in list question

Tags: c#, generics

Basic c# question.  In the sample bellow But the 'is' doesn't like the type variable.  Any ideas there should be a simple answer.

```
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list.Add("one");
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add('3');

    Type desiredType = typeof(System.Int32);

    if (list.Any(w => w is desiredType))
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Putting heterogeneous data in a list is asking for trouble, btw...

Comment: That's a nasty way to use generics, but I guess it's for demonstration only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`w.GetType() == desiredType`.

Why are you abusing generics like that?

Comment: Note that type equality isn't quite the same as `is`; subclasses etc will be confusing...

Comment: Thank you.. IRL our app has a dozen panel types in a collection and wanted a generic way to determine if a panel of a particular type is already open.

Comment: Actually, [AS-CII's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803701/c-is-type-in-list-question/5803762#5803762) should be closer to `is` behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add(2);
list.Add('3');

Type desiredType = typeof(System.Int32);

if (list.Any(w => w.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(desiredType)))
{
    //do something
}
```

Anyway: are you sure you want to create a list of **objects**?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Linq extension method OfType:

list.OfType<> will return an IEnumerable to any items of the specified type.

Comment: This is what you want 9 times out of 10. The other 1/10 time the type isn't known at compile time (ie it's passed as a parameter rather than type parameter of a generic method), in which case you should use AS-CII's method. But usually OfType is what you want. Additionally OfType saves you the cast when you want to retrieve the values, which is handy.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly you have to write `w is System.Int32`..

Answer (score 1):

The delegate is expecting a type or a namespace, but you're supplying a type instance.  Try this:

```
if (list.Any(w => w is Int32))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: How was that "the point"?  Your initial question stated that 'is doesn't like the type variable', and that there should be a simple answer.  Saying `w is Int32` is a lot simpler than getting a type instance and writing `if (list.Any(w => w.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(desiredType)))`